# Debian wheezy change menus background color

Tags: themes, debian, gnome

I am using Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy) and I want to change all popup menus including start menu background color (since it is the same color as my window background). I installed 'GNOME color chooser' pkg. but I could not find the right field to change it.

Comment: try maybe 'gnome-tweak-tool'

Comment: Hi, thanks but gnome-tweak-tool does not contain options for menu colors or I could n't find it.